# Выравнивание изображения по центру

Tags: html, css

Изображение должно размещаться по вертикали и горизонтали по центру, но, как видно по картинке, по вертикали центрирования не происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

HTML:

```
<div class="socialicons">
<div class="main_social">
<img src="http://photos1.blogger.com/x/blogger2/6533/16720282190093/320/140728/plain.gif" class="scimg">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main_social {
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right:0;
}
.social_slideout {
display: none;
}
.socialicons {
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
float: left;
position: relative;
background-color: #444444;
}
.scimg {
line-height: 40px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, почему не работает `line-height: 40px;`. Пробовал также `vertical-align: middle` применять к `scimg`, но визуально оно так же не по центру, чуть ближе к нижней части блока выходит.

Песочница: https://jsfiddle.net/yt7L6fvr/

Comment: Если у Вас `.main_social { position: absolute; }`, то почему не сделать его `top: 5px;`?

Comment: @cyadvert при наведении на иконку она должна увеличиться, потому если я так сделаю она сьедет вниз.

Comment: а можено увидеть код вместе с увеличителем? И потом, при увеличении можно `top` поменять...

Comment: @cyadvert обновил: https://jsfiddle.net/yt7L6fvr/1/ . Думаю менять топ очень неразумно, если есть способ выровнять иначе...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю сделать чуть иначе.

Главное, это класс `grow` на картинке и `transition` в нем.
`.grow:hover` - просто увеличивает картинку в полтора раза.
ну а `top: 5px` ее вертикально позиционирует.

Вот код:

```css
.main_social {
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
right:0;
}
.socialicons {
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
position: relative;
background-color: #444444;
}
.scimg {
line-height: 40px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}

.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover {
 transform: scale(1.5);
 -moz-transition: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="socialicons">
 <div class="main_social"><img src="http://photos1.blogger.com/x/blogger2/6533/16720282190093/320/140728/plain.gif" class="scimg grow"></div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оу, гениально! Я забыл про scale вовсе. И тем не менее, не знаете почему `line-height: 40px;` не выровнял по центру?

Comment: Точно не могу сказать. Я всегда гадаю... играюсь с `line-height`, `position absoulte/relative`, `vertical-align`...  :(

Comment: Я так же работаю, в общем еще раз спасибо за ответ :)